# What is a league duck?

Tags: football, terminology

http://www.theguardian.com/football/2015/feb/10/liverpool-tottenham-hotspur-premier-league-match-report

> Liverpool’s Mario Balotelli breaks league duck to sink Tottenham
>
> Liverpool's Mario Balotelli broke his league duck within nine minutes of coming on as a substitute against Tottenham.

What is a league duck? Does each player have one?

Comment: That poor, poor duck.

Answer (score 3):

It means his first goal in the [Premier] league (for Liverpool). I guess every player "has one" but with some Players it is more important. 
The importance here being it took him quite a while as a striker.

Comment: I've also seen headlines where they say a *team* has broken a duck... is that their first goal in a league? first win in a league? first win in a season?

Comment: I would guess their first win in a season, but if it's a team that's got promoted their first win in a league is also possible. Please note that I'm not a native English speaking person, so I'm not really certain about the team one.

Answer (score 3):

"Duck" means 0 in cricket, as noted in [this question](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/4361/why-is-getting-out-for-zero-is-called-duck-in-cricket). Presumably, breaking one's "league duck" means getting one's first goal in the league, though I have not heard this usage.

See also [Wikipedia on ducks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_for_the_number_0_in_English#.22Love.22.2C_.22duck.22.2C_and_.22nil.22).

Answer (score 3):

'Breaking one's duck' is when someone makes their first score or achieve a particular feat for the first time.

It's actually answered really well in the Stack Exchange English Language & Usage Q&A https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26809/broken-my-duck-is-this-a-common-idiom-phrase

Comment: Thanks! So in baseball, you'd break ducks when you get your first at-bat, first hit, first stolen base, first home run, first grand slam etc?

Comment: It is usually used as a reference to scoring but technically could be applicable to these, yes.